# Collapse rows in long data with many NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

My data set example has 10 rows instead of 5 because of NAs that are in an obvious pattern.

What is an efficient way to collapse a data set like this from 10 rows to 5?

```
df <- structure(list(variable = c("am", "am", "carb", "carb", "cyl", 
"cyl", "disp", "disp", "drat", "drat"), mean_stat = c(0.40625, 
NA, 2.8125, NA, 6.1875, NA, 230.721875, NA, 3.5965625, NA), sd_stat = c(NA, 
0.498990917235846, NA, 1.61519997763185, NA, 1.78592164694654, 
NA, 123.938693831382, NA, 0.534678736070971)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .Names = c("variable", 
"mean_stat", "sd_stat"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly should address the problem upstream. I've seen outputs like this as a result of a bad transpose operation.

Having said that, the NA's can be removed using the tidyr package:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key = "var", value = "val", mean_stat, sd_stat) %>%
  drop_na %>%
  spread(var, val)
```

Comment: Thank you @Stanwood. I agree it would be better handled upstream, but this is the state the data arrived in.

Answer (score 4):

Assume you want to take the first non NA value for each *variable*:

```
df %>% group_by(variable) %>% summarise_all(~ first(na.omit(.)))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  variable  mean_stat     sd_stat
#     <chr>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#1       am   0.406250   0.4989909
#2     carb   2.812500   1.6152000
#3      cyl   6.187500   1.7859216
#4     disp 230.721875 123.9386938
#5     drat   3.596563   0.5346787
```